# Is there a way to define a style in html from python

Tags: python, html, css, flask, pycharm

I'm trying to send some html from my python code.

I'm using the code below.

```
titulo_aux = '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">' + titulo + \
                                         '</span><br><br>'
politica_html += titulo_aux"
```

But i get something like this

```
<span style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;\">
```

I've tried by placing ' \ ' before the  ' " ', and as you see in the code single quotes in the outside and doubles inside.

Comment: don't worry about the backslash. It's just how the string is represented in the console when you print it. Try saving to a file

Comment: Actually, I realized that python is doing good, but the thing is im sending this html in an api. In the json of the API is where the \ is added